# can't find an input, tried by class, by xpath and by css selector

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

So I tried to find this input by many ways and it simple can't be found

```
<div class="col-sm-8 col-lg-10 fb-field-container " style="min-height:26px">
    <div class="fb-inline-field-container form-line" style="display: inherit;vertical-align:top;">
        <input class="form-control tfield" widget="tentry" type="text" required="" aria-required="true" name="nome" value="" id="tentry_1800501884">
        ::after
    </div>
</div>
```

Here some of what I tried:

By class: "col-sm-8 col-lg-10 fb-field-container"

By class: "fb-inline-field-container form-line"

By class: "form-control tfield"

By ID: "tentry_1381418948"

By css selector: "Input[class*='form-control tfield'" and with the 2 other classes

By xpath: "'//div[contains(@class, "form-control tfield")]'" and with the 2 other classes

Most of the errors i got are: 'str' object is not callable

Does anyone have an idea what i can do?

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from pytube import YouTube
from pytube import Channel
import time
import pyautogui

def subir_videos(login, senha):
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
    driver.get('http://simplesprefeitura.pompeu.mg.gov.br/index.php?class=WelcomeView')
    time.sleep(1)
    botao_login = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ("//span[.='Login']"))
    botao_login.click()
    time.sleep(1)
    botao_login_2 = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, ("//span[.='Login']"))
    botao_login_2[1].click()
    time.sleep(1)
    campo_usuario = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ('//div[contains(@class, "fb-inline-field-container form-line")]'))
    # campo_usuario = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ('//div[contains(@class, "col-sm-12 display-flex fb-field-container")]'))
    campo_usuario.click()
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.write(login)
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.hotkey('tab')
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.write(senha)
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.hotkey('enter')
    time.sleep(3)

    botao_pesquisar = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "js-search")
    botao_pesquisar.click()
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.write('videostvlist')
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.hotkey('enter')
    time.sleep(1)

    botao_novo = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Novo')]")
    botao_novo.click()
    time.sleep(1)
```

And here is where im getting trouble

```
    campo_nome = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR("Input[class*='fb-inline-field-container form-line'"))
    campo_nome.click()
    time.sleep(1)
```

UPDATE:
i found that if i hit tab 37 times i get there so i'm using it like this while it works

Comment: Please post the code that shows the request. We can't check the source site and DOM without it.

Comment: Im sorry
I edited and posted my code

Answer (score 0):

To identify the `input` element use either following `css selector` or `xpath`

css selector:

```
input.form-control.tfield[name='nome'][id^='tentry_']
```

or

```
input.form-control.tfield[id^='tentry_']
```

xpath:

```
//input[@class='form-control tfield'][@name='nome'][starts-with(@id, 'tentry_')]
```

or

```
 //input[@class='form-control tfield'][starts-with(@id, 'tentry_')]
```

Ideally your code will be

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.form-control.tfield[name='nome'][id^='tentry_']")
```

Or

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@class='form-control tfield'][@name='nome'][starts-with(@id, 'tentry_')]")
```

---

UPDATE:

It seems its overlapping the element to click on that element induce javascripts executor.

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.form-control.tfield[name='nome'][id^='tentry_']"))
```

Comment: Thank you, 
I tried these codes and got this error:

element click intercepted: Element <input class="form-control tfield" widget="tentry" type="text" name="nome" value="" id="tentry_1176729269"> is not clickable at point (885, 269). Other element would receive the click: <div class="card-body panel-body" style="width: 100%">...</div>

Comment: @RaphaelCampos : Checkout my updated answer and let me know how that goes.

Comment: It didn't crash this time, but it didn't click either

Comment: @RaphaelCampos : do we need to create an account to have a look on the element. If you could provide dummy cred and steps to reproduce will be great.

Comment: Ill see what i can do and let you know, thank you

Answer (score 0):

To identify the element you can use either of the following locator strategies:

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.form-control.tfield[id^='tentry'][widget='tentry'][name='nome']")
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@class='form-control tfield' and starts-with(@id, 'tentry')][@widget='tentry' and @name='nome']")
  ```

---

To click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following locator strategies:

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.form-control.tfield[id^='tentry'][widget='tentry'][name='nome']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='form-control tfield' and starts-with(@id, 'tentry')][@widget='tentry' and @name='nome']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Update

As an alternative you can also use `execute_script()` method as follows:

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  my_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.form-control.tfield[id^='tentry'][widget='tentry'][name='nome']")))
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", my_element)
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  my_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='form-control tfield' and starts-with(@id, 'tentry')][@widget='tentry' and @name='nome']")))
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", my_element)
  ```

Comment: got this message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

Comment: There was a typo, corrected it. Let me know the status.

Comment: Now im getting this message: element click intercepted: Element <input class="form-control tfield" widget="tentry" type="text" name="nome" value="" id="tentry_1905404191"> is not clickable at point (885, 269). Other element would receive the click: <div class="card-body panel-body" style="width: 100%">...</div>

Comment: @RaphaelCampos Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: I tried here, it didn't give any error message, but it didn't click either

Answer (score -1):

Double check that  is not inside a shadow dom or iframe, you may need to switch to it

Comment: Ill need to study what this is first.
Ill study and come back with and answer, thank you

Comment: Sorry I may have given too short an explanation. Some sites have other sites embedded in them using an <iframe> element. In other cases websites can attach a shadow element to their site https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM
In both cases the selenium webdriver won't find an element that is inside one of this. I won't go deeper into this as likely this is not your case. If you try all suggestions and you still can't select the input node I'd start considering these cases.